# SQLite issue in OS X

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am using SQLite in my project. Everything works fine in windows, but in OS X I get error as:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pure Java mode disabled!

at org.sqlite.JDBC.(JDBC.java:34).

What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 0):

Java has the ability to run as a wrapper around existing C libraries. They refer to these as ["native libraries"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). This is handy for a project like SQLite that already has libraries written in C, you don't have to rewrite everything just for Java.

"Pure Java mode" means it is running only Java code and no native libraries. Usually you do this only if the native library is missing. I don't know why it would be disabled.

Either SQLite JDBC driver is mistakenly not seeing the SQLite library ([for which there is an open bug](https://github.com/netcharm/sqlite-jdbc/issues/34)), or you're missing the native/C SQLite library. [According to these instructions](https://github.com/netcharm/sqlite-jdbc/blob/b355cf397fde2751efab9dddbd14314a366d96ba/SQLiteJDBC.wiki#Run_in_PureJava_mode), you might be able to configure the library manually to use the native library with `sqlite.purejava=false`.